# undefined method `total_pages' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, kaminari

i'm trying to use kaminari to paginate my array.

I use the paginate_array method in my controller which then pass the paginatable array to the view that uses a partial view to render.

The rendering is fine but i get a "undefined method total pages for Array" in the server log and some errors in the browser console.

controller :

```
@machines_available = @machines.to_a
  @machines_pagin = Kaminari.paginate_array(@machines_available).page(params[:page]).per(4)
```

index view :

```
<%= render "recherche_results", machineResults: @machines_pagin %>
```

partial view :

```
<%= paginate machineResults %>
```

Comment: Do you also have will_paginate gem in your Gemfile.lock? It can cause various conflicts with Kaminari.

Comment: Kaminari relies on an active record relation so you can't pass it an array.  If you do @machines= Machine.where(blah blah blah) it will work.

Comment: but the paginate_array method is specifically made to pass in an array. This is supposed to return a "paginable" version of the array. I don't have will paginate Lark